# Overlapping bar charts in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, fixed, tableau-desktop, level-of-detail

I want to create overlapping bar chart in tableau like following:
[the bars with light shade show overall grade distribution for month of june and the darker shade bars show data for particular instructor id selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Zde.png)

What exactly I want to do is do a comparison for grade distribution for overall data versus the instructor id I select. I wrote lod for calculating the fixed overall value like this:{ FIXED [grade], [month] : COUNTD([record_id]) } and add this to the row shelf. Next I just add COUNTD([record_id]) to the row shelf to be able to check the grade distribution at instructor level.Whenever I select any instructor id in filter, calculation changes to the instructor level. But I want only one of the overlapping bars to show intructor level grade distribution whith the main fixed graph showing the overall grade distribution. I want to use month field as a filter for both the bar charts which is why I included in the LOD expression. How can I do this in tableau?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), that being said:

### Verify your data's LOD

Seems like there may be an error in your FIXED LOD Expression, although it is hard to tell as you did not provide a hierarchy of your data.

```
{FIXED [grade], [month] : COUNTD([record_id])}
```

This calculation will fix your `[record_id]` to `[grade]` and `[month]`. Based off your explanation above every teacher seems to have an association with record_id for a month and a grade (*I am assuming*) and since your expression sits at finer level than the teacher level, it will split for teacher filters. Specifically [this article on aggregation with FIXED LOD Expressions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_replication.htm) explains what is going on in view level compared to the expression level.

Once sorted, you can then...

### Create a Dual Axis Bar Chart

- Bring your bucketed columns to the column shelf.
- Bring the two measure you wish to compare to the rows shelf.
- Right click one of your measure pills and select dual axis.
- In your Marks Pane make sure bar is selected; individually edit the size for each one of your continuous measures; note they are overlapping, make sure you size down the one in front.

See more on [dual axis visualizations here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiple_measures.htm).